# Editing the CSS of a drag-and-drop template?

Tags: mailchimp

I cannot for the life of me find where I can edit the CSS of a drag-and-drop template. The Mailchimp knowledge base is useless and hasn't returned any results.

Anyone know where I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't think it's possible. You have to export the template as HTML and then re-import as a Code Your Own template.